# Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.pdb not loaded

Tags: debugging, asp.net-core, class-library, asp.net-core-mvc, pdb-files

I have a ASP.NET 5 , MVC 6  project which has reference to a CL in the same solution.

When I try to debug I am unable to enter to the CL's breakpoints.

When I come to the function calling the CL and hit `F11` it just continues , so it doesn't enter into the function for debug.

When I debug  and get over to the function of the CL and choose "Step into specific" and choose the function it says :

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.pdb not loaded.

Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.pdb contains the debug information required to find the source for the module Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.dll

Module Information 
   Version : 6.00.0.10417
   Original Location : <path in local disk>

Try one of the following options :
   Change existing PDB and binary search paths and retry:

        Microsoft Symbbol Servers
```

So when I try to get it load from microsoft symbol server it says :

Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.pdb could not be found in the selected paths

My main project is in MVC 6 and my dll is target framework : .Net 4.5.2

Answer (score 0):

I think that due to the beta nature the pdb files are not on the symbol servers.  I would assume that after RTM (remember VS is RC but asp.net 5 is very much still beta) they would be added to the symbol servers.

If you need support before that you can clone the asp.net MVC repository (https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc.git) to a location outside your project.  Then in the global.json (solution level file) add that path to the project property.  This will instruct the compiler to look there for dependency resolution.   The compiler will always attempt to resolve dependency using local source over nuget package.  In Visual Studio right click on references > restore packages.  You should see the package icon change to indicate source. Then you can simply build, and step directly into the source.

Comment: Can you please give me some details on how to do it. I downloaded the file to local. But there are no pdb files , and I cannot build the project on github to generate the pdb. Which file should I point on on the project.json(I dont have global.json but have project.json where there is a list of dependencies suck as "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta4",)  @Gerald

Answer (score 0):

This error can be occurred because of a wrong doing in code. I got this error once where I was implementing a base class and overriding its method without a base method call where my db context was initialized. But in my controller I was trying to use the db context which is still not initialized which caused a null reference error. Once I fixed it this error disappeared.

```
public class MyController : BaseController 
{
  private MyService _myService;

  protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
  {
   //I missed the base call here
   //base.Initialize(requestContext);
   
    _myService = new MyService(myDbContext);
  }
}

public class BaseController : Controller
{
  public MyDbContext myDbContext { get; set; }

  protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
  {
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
    myDbContext = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<MongoDbContext>();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting the `bin` folder and rebuilding the solution.

Comment: did not worked!